# Blazor WebAssembly Garbage Collector innards

Tags: multithreading, garbage-collection, blazor-webassembly

As far as I understand, the Blazor WebAssembly runtime is single-threaded.

Can someone describe or point to a reference that explains how the garbage collector execution is interleaved with the rest of the Blazor application?

I would like to understand its concurrency details.

- Does the garbage collector run on the same thread as the UI?
- Is it generational?
- If that is the case, will a full garbage collection stop the world
  until complete or is it executed in chunks to keep the UI responsive?
- Is it done on a high level (i.e. using Tasks) or is it performed at a
  lower level? (perhaps invoked by the IL bytecode interpreter in a cooperative way?)